# Ajax request responsetext is empty in IE11

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

im using jquerys ajax function to call a PHP-Script, which returns a number, which indicates if the script failed or succeded. The Problem is that, in IE11, if i try to use the responsetext to check the returncode, it always returns a Blank String, wether the script fails or succeeds. If i use the Dev-Tools of IE, the responsetext of the request is shown correctly, only if i try to check the number within the code it is blank. Chrome & FF are working just fine.

Here is my Code:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
            'beforeSend' : function(xhr) 
            {
                xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=utf8');
            },
        });

    $.ajax({
        url:"phpscripts/saveErgebnisse.php",
        type:"POST",
        datatype:"html",
        cache:false,
        data:{
        spielid:spielid,
        manschaft1:manschaft1,
        manschaft2:manschaft2,
        random:Math.random()
        },
        complete:function(xhr,status)
        {
            if(xhr.status==200){
                if(xhr.responseText==1){<-----Is blank
                    $(event.target.parentNode).effect("highlight",{"color":"#33cc33"},300);
                }
                else
                {
                    $(event.target.parentNode).effect("highlight",{"color":"#cc3333"},300);
                }
            }
        },
    });
```

The called Script:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once "../includes/functions.php";
require_once "../includes/classes.php";
header('charset=utf8');


$userid=$_SESSION["userid"];
$manschaft1=!empty($_POST['manschaft1'])?$_POST['manschaft1']:0;
$manschaft2=!empty($_POST['manschaft2'])?$_POST['manschaft2']:0;
$spielid=!empty($_POST['spielid'])?$_POST['spielid']:die(0);


$manschaft1=is_numeric($manschaft1)?$manschaft1:die(0);
$manschaft2=is_numeric($manschaft2)?$manschaft2:die(0);
$spielid=is_numeric($spielid)?$spielid:die(0);

$db= new DatenbankConnection;


//check nach ablaufdatum
$anpfiff=$db->query("Select anpfiff from spiele_tippspiel where spielid=$spielid");
$anpfiff=mysqli_fetch_assoc($anpfiff);
$anpfiff=$anpfiff["anpfiff"];
if(time()-strtotime($anpfiff)>0){
    die(0);
}


if($db->query(
    'Insert INTO tipps_tippspiel 
    SET manschaft1='.$manschaft1.',
    manschaft2='.$manschaft2.',
    userid='.$userid.',
    spielid='.$spielid.'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    manschaft1='.$manschaft1.',
    manschaft2='.$manschaft2.',
    userid='.$userid.',
    spielid='.$spielid.'
    ')==1){
echo 1;
}else{
echo 0;
}
```

thx for helping

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your `console`? Because I see 2 extra commas that aren't supposed to be there. Line 5 and line 30. Also `< -----Is blank` doesn't have a comment tag `//` before it. Finally `spielid`, `manschaft1`, `manschaft2` are not defined anywhere. So unless they're defined anywhere else that may also break it

Comment: Unluckily the Console Shows no Errors. I added <---is blank only to clarify, its not part of the actual code. Spielid, manschaft1 and manschaft2 are defined earlier and do contain numbers. I checked them and the values are correct. Its like the responsetext is send after the code-runtime, cause its empty when i output it to the console, but its right when i look into the post requests responsetext. Google said that it may be a problem with caching, but setting cache:false does not change anyhting.

Comment: Did removing the 2 extra commas fix anything?

Comment: No, doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: Can you try to use `success` instead of `complete`? Or maybe [`deferred.done`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) or [`deferred.always`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)?

Comment: success gives a blank string as result, "success" as status and the xhr object, whith readyState 4, status 200, statusText OK and... a blank string as responsetext. Done and always are behaving exactly similar.